# NSInvalidArgumentException coming on modal view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, exception

Some time getting given below exception some times on my tester device but not always. I am not understanding why the app crashes some time but not always and why it crashe some time. I am collection the exception using crashlytics.

```
[[Shared instance].myTabbar presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

**Exception Type:** NSInvalidArgumentException

**Reason:** Application tried to present modally an active controller .

Comment: Doesn't the **Reason** tell you the, err, reason?

Comment: Your imagePicker is on screen already and you're trying to re-present it modally. That's a no-no.

Comment: OKay, Now i understand the Reason text, Thanks jmstone